# how to benchmark pypspark queries?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, benchmarking

I have got a simple pyspark script and I would like to benchmark each section.

```
# section 1: prepare data
df = spark.read.option(...).csv(...)
df.registerTempTable("MyData")

# section 2: Dataframe API
avg_earnings = df.agg({"earnings": "avg"}).show()

# section 3: SQL
avg_earnings = spark.sql("""SELECT AVG(earnings)
                            FROM MyData""").show()
```

Do generate reliable measurements one would need to run each section multiple times. My solution using the python **time** module looks like this.

```
import time
for _ in range(iterations):
    t1 = time.time()
    df = spark.read.option(...).csv(...)
    df.registerTempTable("MyData")

    t2 = time.time()
    avg_earnings = df.agg({"earnings": "avg"}).show()

    t3 = time.time()
    avg_earnings = spark.sql("""SELECT AVG(earnings)
                            FROM MyData""").show()
    t4 = time.time()
   
    write_to_csv(t1, t2, t3, t4)
```

My Question is how would one benchmark each section ? Would you use the time-module as well ? How would one disable caching for pyspark ?

---

Edit:
Plotting the first 5 iterations of the benchmark shows that pyspark is doing some form of caching.
[image: benchmark of section 1]

How can I disable this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't benchmark using `show`, it only calculates and returns the top 20 rows.

Second, in general, PySpark API and Spark SQL share the same Catalyst Optimizer behind the scene, so overall what you are doing (using `.agg` vs `avg()`) is pretty much similar and don't have much difference.

Third, usually, benchmarking is only meaningful if your data is really big, or your operation is much longer than expected. Other than that, if the runtime difference is only a couple of minutes, it doesn't really matter.

Anyway, to answer your question:

1. Yes, there is nothing wrong to use `time.time()` to measure.
2. You should use `count()` instead of `show()`. `count` would go forward and compute your entire dataset.
3. You don't have to worry about `cache` if you don't call it. Spark won't cache unless you ask for it. In fact, you shouldn't cache at all when benchmarking.
4. You should also use static allocation instead of dynamic allocation. Or if you're using Databricks or EMR, use a fixed amount of workers and don't auto-scale it.

Comment: Thank you. There are a lot of useful information within your answer.  Now the only thing I need to figure out is: How I can stop pyspark from caching any Data.

Comment: Look at #3 above: Spark won't cache unless you tell it to cache

Comment: Count is better than show, but still not perfect, because Spark can figure out that it does not actually need to compute some stuff because it sees that it can not affect the nr of rows. Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/performance-in-apache-spark-benchmark-9-different-techniques-955d3cc93266 "One action that can come to your mind is the function count(). However with the count, there is this problem, that to evaluate how many rows are represented by the resulting DataFrame, Spark doesn’t always need to execute all transformations. "